# Mystery show where an airplane disappears

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

Years ago, my mom was watching this show and it seemed pretty interesting so I went ahead and watched it with her. I can't remember the name but I remember what happened in the episode. It might have been the pilot and I think it was one during the time *Lost* was just getting started and it would have played on one of the main stations like ABC, NBC, or FOX.

**Plot:**

As a plane was landing, it disappeared and then reappeared. So the main characters came to investigate. Everyone on board witness something different or had something different done to them. Through the episode they were discovering that it was what the person was thinking right before they disappeared. For example, one lady was thinking about her dead husband and then she claimed that she saw her dead husband. Another guy was was afraid of flying and was thinking about the plain crashing, and then his body was burned to a crisp. Later on the passengers where slowly forgetting about what they saw and even the dead guy was slowly coming back to life.

Do you know what this tv show is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the 2nd episode ('The Friendly Skies') of the short-lived mystery show [Miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracles_%28TV_series%29) from 2003.

> When a plane disappears for 64 seconds just before landing, [the invastigative organization] SQ is called to investigate. They discover that each of the passengers had a different experience during that time, and their experience was exactly what they were thinking when the plane disappeared.

The passengers later forget what they saw. Here are the first 10 minutes: